# Angular display value of model binded date value in date input field

Tags: angular, date, input

I am passing this model to the view:

```
export class ProgramModel {
  programId: bigint;
  category = new CategoryModel();
  name: string;
  description: string;
  shortDescription: string;
  support: string [];
  address: string;
  location: [];
  areaServed: string;
  baseLocation: string;
  website: string;
  topic: string [];
  ownerLid: string;
  keywords: string[] = [];
  startDate: Date;
  endDate: Date;
  notification: boolean;
  daysForNotice: number;
  filter: string [];
  active: boolean;
  approved: boolean;
  status: string;
  contact: ContactModel[] = [];
  departmentContact: ContactModel[] = [];
}
```

The values `startDate` and `endDate` are presented like this:

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="startDate">Start Date</label>
          <input style="line-height: 20px" type="date" class="form-control" id="startDate"
                 [(ngModel)]="model.startDate" name="date">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="endDate">End Date</label>
          <input style="line-height: 20px" type="date" class="form-control" id="endDate"
                 [(ngModel)]="model.endDate" name="date">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Simply creating a new db record using this works fine, but reusing the code for the edit page I have found that I can't get those date input's to display the previously selected value like I can with the other fields.

[image]

This is the value of start and end date when the page loads:
`startDate: Sat Jan 29 2022 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)`
`endDate: Fri Mar 11 2022 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)`

And this is where I make them into a date:

```
this.programService.getProgramByID(item.programId).subscribe(
      (theProgram) => {
        theProgram.startDate = new Date(theProgram.startDate);
        theProgram.endDate = new Date(theProgram.endDate);
        this.model = theProgram;
      });
```

How can I make those date input's display the values?

Comment: What is the actual string you’re getting ? Is it the string in your question? Because that is a normal string and not a date. I guess you’d have to convert it (new Date(string))?

Comment: Hey I edited the question to show that I'm already setting start and end date to dates. I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi. I do it [like this](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/ClientApp/src/app/pages/person/edit/edit.component.html#L40)